# Disable diagonal movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I would love to disable diagonal movement in this movement script, but I don't have a clue how to do it. I want my player to move whenever I click on the map, it is moving but including diagonals which I want to get rid off. I would like to also makes my animations works. Could you guys help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1f, 10f)]
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    Touch touch;
    private Vector3 touchPosition, whereToMove;
    private bool isWalking = false;

    float previousDistanceToTouchPos, currentDistanceToTouchPos;

    private Animator anim;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isWalking)
            currentDistanceToTouchPos = (touchPosition - transform.position).magnitude;

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                previousDistanceToTouchPos = 0;
                currentDistanceToTouchPos = 0;
                isWalking = true;
                touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                touchPosition.z = 0;
                whereToMove = (touchPosition - transform.position).normalized;
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(whereToMove.x * moveSpeed, whereToMove.y * moveSpeed, );
            }
        }

        if (currentDistanceToTouchPos > previousDistanceToTouchPos)
        {
            isWalking = false;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }

        if (isWalking)
        {
            previousDistanceToTouchPos = (touchPosition - transform.position).magnitude;
        }

        float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");


        // If the player wants to move and is not walking.
        // The future position is calculated.
        if (horizontalMovement != 0 && !isWalking)
        {
            whereToMove += Vector3.right * horizontalMovement;
        }
        else if (verticalMovement != 0 && !isWalking)
        {
            whereToMove += Vector3.up * verticalMovement;
        }

        // If the future position is different from the current one, it is because the player wants to move the character.
        //if (whereToMove != transform.position)
        //{
        //    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, whereToMove, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        //    if (!isWalking) { isWalking = true; }
        //}

        //if (horizontalMovement != 0 || verticalMovement != 0)
        //{

        //}

        // Animating the player when moving

        anim.SetFloat("x", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetFloat("y", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

    }
}
```

I would like to also makes my animations works. Could you guys help me? I'm newbie, so please be detailed

Comment: To clarify - do you want your character to first move up/down and then left/right? Sort of like a knight on a chessboard (as opposed to a bishop)?.

Comment: I'm creating RPG game, so I want my player to move towards my destination point after point it on the screen, no metter which direction first. To be honest I want him to make a shortest path.

Comment: Try using the built-in navigation provided by Unity first. If you want to find the shortest path, you will probably won't need to implement your own path finding. I've never used it but it looks a matured feature: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html

Comment: Ok, forget about path finding. I just want to be disable diagonals on this script. Would any of you be able to help me?